# Client & server side form validation with AngularJS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, validation, angularjs, server-side

How to avoid duplication and show the same error messages using AngularJS client-side validation & Rails server-side one?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://codetunes.com/2013/server-form-validation-with-angular/